# adding value for .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*the HTML below*

```
<div class="commentlinks">
    <a class="commentlinked blogcount">3</a>
    <a class="commentlinked fbcount">2</a>
    <a class="commentlinked disqcount">1</a>
    <a class="allcommentcount"></a>
</div>
```

*with this jQuery*

```
$('.commentlinks').each(function() {
var currentValue = parseInt($(".blogcount").text());
var currentValue2 = parseInt($(".fbcount").text());
var currentValue3 = parseInt($(".disqcount").text());
var newValue = currentValue + currentValue2 + currentValue3;
$(".allcommentcount").text(newValue);
});
```

Returns this successfully http://jsfiddle.net/hQzZQ/22/

3
    2
    1
    6

**but** when i have this html

```
<div class="commentlinks">
    <a class="commentlinked blogcount">3</a>
    <a class="commentlinked fbcount">2</a>
    <a class="commentlinked disqcount">1</a>
    <a class="allcommentcount"></a>
</div>

<div class="commentlinks">
    <a class="commentlinked blogcount">7</a>
    <a class="commentlinked fbcount">6</a>
    <a class="commentlinked disqcount">1</a>
    <a class="allcommentcount"></a>
</div>
```

It Returns http://jsfiddle.net/hQzZQ/23/

3 2 1 74
7 6 1 74

why is it returning it incorrectly help me fix it please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `find` or `children` to select the elements in the current context. Also, use `parseInt(.., 10)` to parse numbers.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sym7H/**

```
$('.commentlinks').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var currentValue = parseInt($this.find(".blogcount").text(), 10);
    var currentValue2 = parseInt($this.find(".fbcount").text(), 10);
    var currentValue3 = parseInt($this.find(".disqcount").text(), 10);
    var newValue = currentValue + currentValue2 + currentValue3;
    $this.find(".allcommentcount").text(newValue);
});
```

---

If your document is well-structured, you can also use `.children("a")` to find the elements, then use `.eq(..)` or `.slice(.., 1)` to select the elements. This has an improved efficiency.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sym7H/1/**

```
$('.commentlinks').each(function() {
    var $anchors = $(this).children("a"),
        currentValue = parseInt($anchors.eq(0).text(), 10),
        currentValue2 = parseInt($anchors.eq(1).text(), 10),
        currentValue3 = parseInt($anchors.eq(2).text(), 10),
        newValue = currentValue + currentValue2 + currentValue3;
    $anchors.eq(3).text(newValue);
});
```

Comment: bad solution to use find. use the context instead !

Comment: @RoyiNamir `$("selector", this)` is equal to and [slightly slower](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) than `$(this).find("selector")`. If the document has the exact structure as in the question, `children()` should be used.

Comment: @RobW From the link you posted: "Internally, selector context is implemented with the .find() method, so $('span', this) is equivalent to $(this).find('span')."  Royi's solution is less characters and MUCH easier to read.  Don't want to get into performace debate, but in this case using .find is probably not buying him anything, however parseInt(text,10) IS the safe way to parse his numbers

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hQzZQ/24/

```
$('.commentlinks').each(function() {
var currentValue = parseInt($(".blogcount",this).text());
var currentValue2 = parseInt($(".fbcount",this).text());
var currentValue3 = parseInt($(".disqcount",this).text());
var newValue = currentValue + currentValue2 + currentValue3;
$(".allcommentcount",this).text(newValue);
});
```